# How do I pass the language through ajax request

Tags: ajax, i18n-l10n

I have an ajax function in the javascript file that calls for the data in a custom module. But the problem is it always get the data for the default language. In my case it is 'en'. How do I get the data for another language.

```
$language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();
```

This method always returns the default language for ajax requests. How do I get the data for the language that is mentioned in the url.

**ajax**:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/gallery/view", 
    method :'POST',
    data: {
        category : category,
        propertyId : propertyId,
        isCorporate : isCorporate,
        brandId : brandId,
    },
    success: function(result){}
});
```

**routing** :

```
eme_gallery.view:
  path: '/gallery/view'
  defaults:
      _controller: 'Drupal\eme_gallery\Controller\ViewGalleryImage::view'
      _title: 'Image Gallery'
  requirements:
      _permission: 'access content'
```

Comment: How is the langauge for your site determined? URL? Prefix? Session?

Comment: @Jaypan from the url prefix. eg: www.url.com/ja/html

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the URL of your AJAX call to include the language prefix. So this:

```
url: "/gallery/view",
```

Will be this:

```
url: "/ja/gallery/view",
```

Comment: This doesn’t work for the english language. If I write /en/ it doesn’t work

Comment: Do not include any prefix (en, ja etc) for the default language. You would only use `/gallery/view`